# How to get 13 numbers behind decimals of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I use the following method to get the current latitude & longitude:

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager == null) {
                Toast.makeText(LocationsListActivity.this,
                        "Location Manager Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location == null)
                location = locationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

but the problem the lat and lng I got only have 8 numbers behind the decimal (lat: 52.51491445, lng: 13.39044515)
What I wanna have is the lat and lng I got has 13 numbers behind the decimal.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure that lat has only 8 decimal places? or it is just string representation of this value ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point ... what you see is just a string ... and maybe Double.toString() makes it looks like it has only 8 decimal places

Comment: Is this possible to get the latitude and longitude with more than 12 decimals.?

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the setAccurary() method and the setPowerRequirement() method of Criteria.